# Run Shiny App on Windows Server

Tags: r, shiny, windows-server, windows-task-scheduler

I want to run a Shiny application on a Windows Server. The shiny application runs on Port 8080 and the traffic is routed through IIS. Everything works fine, but from time to time the application crashes. So far I've written a small R script which proofs whether the application is available and if not it restarts the Shiny app. The script is called by Task Scheduler. This solution is kind of messy and the Scheduler does not work as expected.

Are there any similar set-ups or are there any pre-defined solutions, such as the Shiny Server? (I'm not allowed to install a VM. Unfortuentaly, it must be a Windows-only solution.)

Comment: I think running a Task Scheduler Job is the only solution you have here... I dont understand why the company doesnt allow `VM`. You can maybe try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-client/install-on-windows

Comment: Did you think about check your logs and try to solve the problem once instead of reparing your service each time it's crashed?

Comment: You might be interested in a process manager like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). It's primarily intended for Node.js apps, but you can use it with anything. There's a brief write-up on usage with R here: https://www.rplumber.io/docs/hosting.html#pm2. That's for plumber, but it could easily be adapted to run Shiny apps.

Comment: @Jan I have been looking at multiple resources, but can't seem to find out how to run a ShinyApp on an IIS web server... I am allowed to run virtual machines it's just a matter of figuring things out, but I'm just not succeeding... I have created a Linux VM machine on which I can run Shiny server with a shiny app. I run a Microsoft Server 2016 VM to setup a test IIS web server. I have created a bridged network connection for both VM's so I can access the location of the shiny app on all my machines, but I don't know  how to rout the shiny app to IIS. Any help appreciated!! Thank you

Comment: Hi @smoens you can use the [ARR](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) to redirect the traffic to the vm. You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis).

Comment: @Jan thanks a lot, going to try it out this week, this is just the push I needed!